# Regex to match multiple subdirectories in a URL

Tags: .net, regex

Is it possible to write a regex to capture sub paths that come after `https://localhost:443/one/12345678/two/12345678`? Given the URL below, I would like to capture `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`:

```
https://localhost:443/one/12345678/two/12345678/a/b/c/d?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3
```

This is what I have so far, but it only captures `a`:

```
[\w\W]*one\/\w{8}\/two\/\w{8}(?:\/?([\w]))
```

Comment: Remove `[\w\W]*`. What is the code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that's just o match anything up to one. maybe I can replace that with "." => .*one\/\w{8}\/two\/\w{8}(?:\/?([\w]))

Comment: No, you do not need that when you extract. Show the code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, what code are you referring to? I'm testing this on [link](https://regex101.com/r/igvKTf/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?<=/one/\w{8}/two/\w{8}/[^?#]*?)[^/?#]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/igvKTf/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<=/one/\w{8}/two/\w{8}/[^?#]*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `/one/`, then eight word chars (`\w{8}`), `/two/`, another eight word chars, `/` and then any zero or more chars other than `?` and `#` as few as possible (with `[^?#]*?`)
- `[^/?#]+` - one or more chars other than a `/`, `#` and `?`.

Comment: If there is any problem with this solution, I'd like to know. Note that .NET regex supports lookbehind patterns of unknown length.